# Change IIS SSL settings using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, iis, ansible, powershell-2.0

I am completely new to Windows PowerShell.
I am trying to change the IIS's default web site's SSL settings from 
`Required SSL = false and client certificate = ignore` to 
`Required SSL = true and client certificate = accept` using powershell (I have to configure it to ansible playbook)
I have searched but didn't get any solution.

[image]

Kindly help. Any leads or solution will be appreciated. :)
Thank You

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `Set-WebConfiguration` cmdlet. There's a great [configuration reference on IIS.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/access) that you can use to find the valid values - in this case `Ssl` and `SslNegotiateCert`:

```
Set-WebConfiguration -Location "[sitename]" -Filter 'system.webserver/security/access' -Value 'Ssl,SslNegotiateCert'
```

Comment: Thanks. That link is a great help. What is "[sitename]"  here? And from which location shall I run the PowerShell?

Comment: In place of [sitename] you should put the name of the website or path to the app or virtual directory you want to set this for. Running on the server as a local admin or as a user that has been delegated permissions to manage the site/app/vdir in question should do

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `Set-WebConfiguration` does **not** work on *attributes* in a reliable manner.

What you instead want to use is:

```
$cfgSection = Get-IISConfigSection -Location "{siteName}/{appName}" -SectionPath "system.webServer/security/access";
Set-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $cfgSection -AttributeName "sslFlags" -AttributeValue "Ssl, SslNegotiateCert";
```

Note that after you use `Set-IISConfigAttributeValue` (and commit the change, if you're doing a delayed commit), you can't use that instance of $cfgSection to make subsequent changes; you'll have to fetch another instance first.

PS: If you want to see what's in the config before you mess with it (or afterwards), the authoritative settings are here:  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

Or you can continue the above code and add `Get-IISConfigAttributeValue -ConfigElement $cfgSection -AttributeName "sslFlags";`